# How to open next tab in accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I am trying to make an accordion which has first tab open. A button should open next tab and close the previous one.
So far it just closes tab but doesn't open next one and I have hard time figuring out how to make it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cat').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp('fast');
    $(".a-content").next().css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

```css
.a-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.a-content {
  display: none;
}

.a-content.default {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a-section">
  <h4 class="a-toggle">1. Title</h4>
  <div class="a-content default">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <button type="button" class="cat">Continue</button>
  </div>
  <h4 class="a-toggle">2. Title</h4>
  <div class="a-content">
    <p>More text</p>
    <button type="button" class="cat">Continue</button>
  </div>
  <h4 class="a-toggle">3. Title</h4>
  <div class="a-content">
    <p>Even more text</p>
    <button type="button" class="cat">Continue</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**One line solution**

You need two things:

- set a new `next()` because `.a-content` is not  the next sibling after itself, it has `h4` between
- then on click you need to set the parent to that element clicked, by using `$(this)`

You can improve this by adding a class instead of setting CSS inline

```js
$('.cat').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().slideUp('fast').next().next().addClass('open'); //SlideToggle will work too
});
```

```css
.a-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.a-content {
  display: none;
}

.a-content.default, .a-content.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a-section">
  <h4 class="a-toggle">1. Title</h4>
  <div class="a-content default">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <button type="button" class="cat">Continue</button>
  </div>
  <h4 class="a-toggle">2. Title</h4>
  <div class="a-content">
    <p>More text</p>
    <button type="button" class="cat">Continue</button>
  </div>
  <h4 class="a-toggle">3. Title</h4>
  <div class="a-content">
    <p>Even more text</p>
    <button type="button" class="cat">Continue</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cat').click(function() {
    const parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.slideToggle();
    const next = parent.next().next();
    next.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.a-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.a-content {
  display: none;
}

.a-content.default {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a-section">
  <h4 class="a-toggle">1. Title</h4>
  <div class="a-content default">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <button type="button" class="cat">Continue</button>
  </div>
  <h4 class="a-toggle">2. Title</h4>
  <div class="a-content">
    <p>More text</p>
    <button type="button" class="cat">Continue</button>
  </div>
  <h4 class="a-toggle">3. Title</h4>
  <div class="a-content">
    <p>Even more text</p>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cat').click(function() {
    const $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.slideUp('fast');
    $parent.nextUntil(".a-content").next().css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```